# How can I copy a sheet with drop down boxes in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a weird situation.  I have a workbook that has 6 drop down boxes within one of the sheets.  Everytime I copy the sheet within the same workbook I get a box that pops up that says:

> A formula or sheet you want to move or copy contains the name "drop down name here", which already exists on the destination worksheet.  Do you want to use this version of the name?

Then I just choose *Yes*, but I have to click *Yes* 6 times because that is how many drop downs I have. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this reguarding worksheets...

It should still apply to your dropdown problem though.

Try "localising" your names to worksheets that are going to be copied.
So, if you have a worksheet called "Sheet1"
and a name MyName that refers to range Sheet1!$A$1
then delete MyName and then redefine it as
Sheet1!MyName
refers to
Sheet1!$A$1

Note the "Sheet1!" prefix to the definition of the Name.

You may still run into problems if you use data validation that refers to
drop-down lists where the name of the list is localised to a different
worksheet, or conditional formatting where the "Fomula Is" refers to a named
range that is localised to another sheet.

Probably good practice to avoid duplicating global (not tied to sheet) names
and local names. It can cause confusion over which name is being called.

Jan Karel Pieterse's "Name Manager" is a useful add-in tool for clearing out
names that contain errors, identifying duplicate global/local names,
localising names that you have already defined as global and do not want to
go to the trouble of deleting first, and a whole host of other goodies

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I think that's beyond my knowledge of what's going on here.  I'll try to comprehend what you're telling me and apply it to what I have going on.

Comment: Excellent.  If you still don't get it, just let me know, and I'll see what I can do...